# Eigen + Boost shared Ptr and 32 bit

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, eigen

I have a problem when I move my program to a 32-bit system

```
class Example{
  Eigen::Vector2d test
}
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Example> ExamplePtr;
```

I get the error which is described there

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html)

and there solution is:

```
class Example{
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  Eigen::Vector2d test
}
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Example> ExamplePtr;
```

but this solution is still not working and I have no idea. The program is programmed on Linux 64 bit and now I want to import it on Windows 32-bit.

Do you have any ideas what I can try and do?

---

There Error Message description:

my_program: path/to/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:44:
Eigen::internal::matrix_array::internal::matrix_array()
[with T = double, int Size = 2, int MatrixOptions = 2, bool Align = true]:
Assertion `(reinterpret_cast(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion
is explained here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/UnalignedArrayAssert.html
     READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.

my Error message:
[image: Error]

i try in a main

```
int main(){
ExamplePtr ptr=ExamplePtr(new Example());
}
```

### on 64 bit system this is working

Edit:

What kind of code needs to be changed?

The kind of code that needs to be changed is this:

```
class Foo
{
...
Eigen::Vector2d v;
...
};
...
Foo *foo = new Foo;
```

In other words: you have a class that has as a member a fixed-size vectorizable Eigen object, and then you dynamically create an object of that class.
How should such code be modified?

Very easy, you just need to put a EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW macro in a public part of your class, like this:

```
class Foo
{
...
Eigen::Vector2d v;
...
public:
EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
};
...
Foo *foo = new Foo;
```

This macro makes "new Foo" always return an aligned pointer.

If this approach is too intrusive, see also the Other solutions.

this is there solution for member variables.

Comment: I can't see any reference to EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW on that page. What is your actual "problem"?

Comment: Posts should be self-contained (links can die). Please add sufficient information from the link (at least give the error) into the question so looking at the link is not required. Also give the exact error message or behaviour rather than saying "is still not working", as the latter doesn't mean much to us.

Comment: i have added that part what i thought is important but i am not sure because i have boost::smart_pointer and i have added the error message too

Comment: I still don't know what "still not working" means. Compile error? Runtime error?

Comment: runtime error :) i have added a few thinks the main is not working i get this error above

Comment: Have you recompiled your code for 32 bit, since you say the 64 bit version is working?

Comment: i am using my source file and compile it on 32 bit the problem is Eigen with there pointer -> If you define a structure having members of fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types, you must overload its "operator new" so that it generates 16-bytes-aligned pointers. Fortunately, Eigen provides you with a macro EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW that does that for you.

Comment: But this solving is not working for me and i dont understand the problem with vectorizing

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code? Your operator new seems to be private, so the example shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue is that boost::shared_ptr is not using operator new for memory allocation. I suggest you to use a non-aligned 2D vector type for your member variables:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1,Eigen::DontAlign> Vector2du;
class Example{
  Eigen::Vector2du test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have wrong packing in your project. Please put `#pragma pack(show)` just above your class declaration and compile. If it says anything not equal to 8, put the following code:

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Around all `#include <eigen...>` and possibly your class declaration.

Comment: wrong packing? this program is running on 64bit ? and when i putt #pragma pack(show) nothing happen

Comment: You should recompile and check your compilation log, there will be a new message showing the current packing. Packing is essentially how struct members are aligned, and your issue is exactly about the array not being aligned on 16-byte boundary